# Is ngx_pagespeed disabled for X-Accel-Redirect content?

Tags: nginx, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, x-accel-redirect

i have ngx_pagespeed running with the following configuration

```
pagespeed On;
# only apply conservative filters
pagespeed RewriteLevel OptimizeForBandwidth;
pagespeed FileCachePath /mnt/tmp/nginx-pagespeed-filecache;
pagespeed FileCacheSizeKb            102400;
pagespeed FileCacheCleanIntervalMs   3600000;
pagespeed FileCacheInodeLimit        500000;
pagespeed InPlaceResourceOptimization on;
pagespeed RespectXForwardedProto on;
pagespeed FetchHttps enable;

pagespeed Domain DOMAIN;

# enable optimization of images
pagespeed EnableFilters rewrite_images;
```

It works for normal image requests, but for images which are delivered using the [X-Accel-Redirect](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile) header mechanism ngx_pagespeed does not seem to work.

Is this a known restriction? Or am i doing sth. wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found it, i had to add an additional

```
pagespeed Domain DOMAIN;
```

entry for the the host of the X-Accel-Redirect url.